# How to create programmatically textview in RecyclerView.ViewHolder

Tags: android, android-viewholder

Trying to figure out how to add dynamically changing number of textviews to my viewholder.

Im getting (int) counter from my server, which represent the number of proprties in the viewholder. each viewholder have different number of properties.

How to implement this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your ViewHolder store the new TextViews in a List, and add each TextView to the cell's itemView in the ViewHolder. Should look similar to the code below:

```
ViewGroup viewGroup = (ViewGroup)itemView.findViewById(R.id.your_viewgroups_id); //Usually a LinearLayout or RelativeLayout
List<TextView> textViews = new LinkedList<>();
for (int i = 0; i < count; i++) {
     TextView textView = new TextView(context)
     textViews.add(textView);

     viewGroup.addView(textView);
}
```

Comment: You might want to pass something to `textViews.add();`

Comment: Oh, I forgot. Try getting the parent ViewGroup (like LinearLayout or RelativeLayout) from your itemView with ```ViewGroup viewGroup  = itemView.findViewById(R.id.your_viewgroups_id)```  Then ```viewGroup.add(textView)```

Comment: Try viewGroup.addView(textView); (this is the last time I'll try answering Questions without having Android Studio available, I'm making too many mistakes lol)